# Existence of solution to $tx'(t)=x(t)-1$ by Picard's existence theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the ODE:
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}
ttx'(t)=x(t)-1 \\ 
x(0)=1  
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

I have found that there are infinitely many solutions to the equation: $x(t)=Ct+1, C \in \Bbb R$.

I am wondering how does it agree with Picard's existence theorem. 
If I write $x'(t)=f(t,x(t)) \;$ where $\; f(t,x)=\frac{x-1}{t}$, then $f$ is not continuous in $0$. Can I conclude the theorem doesn't work in the other direction?

Comment: Hint: Uniqueness.

Comment: I think the condition for the uniqueness is $f$ locally lipchitz or something like that

Comment: @JackyChong I can see that the condition for uniqueness doesn't hold, and thus there are infinitely many solutions. But my question is about the existence, it seems like the condition for existence doesn't hold either, and that's what my question is about

Comment: The theorem is about wellposedness, not just existence.

Comment: What do you mean by "wellposedness" ?

Comment: Wellposedness means there exists a unique solution.

Comment: From what I have studied, The condition for existence only (without uniqueness) is that the above $f$ is continuous. If $f$ is also lipchitz in respect to $x$, the solution is unique.

Comment: Those are sufficient conditions.

Comment: The point $(0,1)$ lies outside the domain of the function $(t,x) \mapsto \frac{x-1}{t}$, and Picard's theorem (or, for that matter, theorem on existence and uniqueness for linear ODEs) says nothing about that.

Comment: From your answers I can conclude that the conditions of the theorem are only sufficient, and not necessary?

Comment: To re-iterate the point of @user539887, at $t=0$ your equation is not an ODE, the right side in $\dot x=f(t,x)$ is not only not continuous there, but not even defined. Thus one can only ask if solutions for $t>0$ where it is an ODE with all existence and uniqueness properties can be extended continuously to $t=0$ with the given value. The standard existence theorems do not apply to your problem, you can not even start discussing sufficiency etc.

Comment: @user401516 You are right that the conditions of the theorem are only sufficient, not necessary.  But you **cannot conclude it from my answer**.